# jQuery sum the list numbers value in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, save

Make an input field in which I can only write numbers and submit a submit button. Press the submit button to place the number in a list. Display the numbers in the list below. Make a box with "SUM" ID. Enter the sum of the numbers in the list.

I got stuck to sum the list numbers in a div. 
How can I proceed this in jquery?

How can I make sure the numbers stay in the list for up to half a year? If I start typing in the input field, ensure that it does not lose its value by the end of the session, but will not last forever! If the list changes, make sure that I display is updated on the page and count the amount again. Make a erease(sum) function, which when I call it, erases the numbers received in the parameter from the list.

localStorage.setItem function?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <title>task10</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="task10.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="number" id="ipbox" value=""></p>

<button id="appendList">Send</button>

<ul class="listElement"></ul>
<div id="sum"></div>

</body>
</html>

$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#appendList').click(function(){
      $('.listElement').append($('<li>', {
           text: $('#ipbox').val()
      }));
  });


});
```

Comment: From the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#dom-localstorage): User agents should expire data from the local storage areas only for security reasons or when requested to do so by the user. What you could do, is save the date along with each value, and set a check so that when six months passes, all values older than six months are ignored and removed from localStorage.

Comment: You're probably best off asking two questions. Is this a homework task?

Comment: Please, do not judge me. 
To say you are right.
I've been trying it on day 2. but I do not get anything. A little explanation and code writing would help in the interpretation. Google does not help I'm completely confused at this moment.
Sorry for my question. I'm a beginner. I try to master it but do not teach it well.

Comment: I need help to sum the list numbers in a div. 
And how can write out the result in the sum id div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the sum :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let s = 0;
    $('#appendList').click(function(){
        $('.listElement').append($('<li>', {
            text:$('#ipbox').val()
        }));
    s = s + parseInt($('#ipbox').val());
    $('#sum').text(s);
    });
});
```